# Content manager installer problems with listening port

Tags: content-manager

I'm installing the Web 8.5 content manager on Windows Server 2016. It's a local installation, and my hostnames won't be available via DNS, so I started off by adding entries in the hosts file for `sdlweb` and `topman` pointing to the interface where Tridion will run. In the installer website step, I specified `sdlweb` and port 80. The intention is to have topology manager run at `topman` and port 80.

At this point, the installer tells me that it can't go any further because the port is occupied. There are no websites configured in IIS yet, but:

```
(Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 80).OwningProcess
```

gives me the SYSTEM process. This makes sense: I expect HTTP.SYS to be listening here, even if the port is not truly "occupied".

Changing my hosts file so that the names don't match the ones I'm entering in the installer allows me to proceed, albeit with a warning about being unable to validate the host header.

Unfortunately, this isn't an effective workaround because then later in the process the installer reports a 500 error from the topology manager, presumably because it can't find the endpoint.

This is preventing me from achieving a scripted installation to my preferred design. I'll end up installing without host headers and on distinct ports, and then have to fix everything afterwards.

Why does the installer perform this check? (And what exactly is it checking? Is it just testing for an open port?) 
What effective workarounds might be possible? 
Given that I will now have to fix things up post-install, where are the two host header values used? In other words, if I only change the bindings in IIS, what would break, and how can I prevent that?

Faced with this, what do other people do? Does everyone just give up on host headers and use port numbers?

Answer (score 2):

So eventually I gave up on trying to configure host headers in the installer, and let it use a distinct port number for topology manager. After some wrestling, I now have a list of the places where you need to manually update your configuration having done this:

Firstly, open up `%TRIDION_HOME%web\WebUI\WebRoot\Web.config`

As noted by Velu, you need to update the `Tridion.WCF.RedirectTo` key. 
Further down there's the possibility of uncommenting `baseAddressPrefixFilters` and adding names. I haven't done this, and I don't know what breaks if you don't.

Yet further down there's configuration for `EclBinaryEndpoint`. I'm not using ECL, so I don't know if you need to fix this one up or not.

You also need to update two Environment variables: `TRIDION_CONFIGURATION_URL` and `TRIDION_TTM_SERVICEURL`
The latter of these is needed by the topology manager cmdlets. I'm not sure what breaks if you don't fix the former.

Finally, (I hope) you need to open up `%TRIDION_HOME%hubs\NotificationHub\Web.config` and edit the `ContentManager.BackplaneHub.Url` key. 
Otherwise you'll see "Could not connect to the Connection hub" errors in the notification area.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, I will install the IIS and roles and then will delete the default website in IIS and then Installer to Install the **CMS** on hostname value as empty port number value as 80 or **localhost 80**, and **Topology Manager** on **localhost 81**.

Once successful installation will review the CMS access by http://localhost

if we want to change the hostname localhost to **sdlweb** then add this hostname in the host's file and then find **sdlweb** in IIS binding for SDL Web.

Open the web.config in the below directory

> \%TRIDION_HOME%\web\WebUI\WebRoot\

and ensure that the below line:

> <add key="Tridion.WCF.RedirectTo" value="localhost:80"/>

Matches that of the IIS binding information. For example, if you have a binding of **sdlweb** on port 80, then you'd need to change this to:

> <add key="Tridion.WCF.RedirectTo" value="sdlweb:80"/>

And then restart the SDL Tridion Service Host

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Velu. Looks like a vote for "just give up on host headers and use port numbers"